# PostgreSQL: native library learn the filesystem path that was used to load it?

Tags: postgresql

From the `_PG_init` of a dynamic library that postgres has loaded (either because of a function declaration referring to it, or just `LOAD` *pathname*; in SQL), is there any call I can make, not platform-dependent, to find what full pathname was used to load me? (I could get the `dynamic_library_path` and try to find myself on it, but that's error prone, and if the `LOAD` command was used, or a full path was used in a function declaration, then all bets are off.)

It seems like there's a linked list in `dfmgr.c` with exactly the full path I want ... if it were not declared `static`, and if there were an easy way to know something like my own handle to match in the list....

Comment: Not AFAIK. Why would you want this? What's the underlying problem you are attempting to solve with this?

Comment: Part of the Spock's Brain thing I'm working on for pljava.